# Change the navigation ul li based on the clicked country

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object-oriented

I'm trying to create a very simple jQuery plugin in the object-oriented way. Now, I'm not sure whether the code I produced is correct and efficient OO programming. The plugin's aim is to change the navigation `ul  li` based on the clicked country.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5yor0Ldn/4/)

```
// Widget container
(function($) {
// Widget container plugin
    $.fn.myWidget = function () {
        this.each (function () {
            // Vars
            var item = $ (this);

            // Set events
            item.click (function (e) {
                if (e) e.preventDefault ();
                combine_all(item);
            });
        });
    };

    //uk navigation
    var uk_navigation = '<ul>'
        +'<li id="menu-1">UK stuff</li>'
        +'<li id="menu-2">UK phones</li>'
        +'</ul>';

    //global navigation
    var global_navigation = '<ul>'
        +'<li id="menu-1">EU stuff</li>'
        +'<li id="menu-2">EU phones</li>'
        +'</ul>';

    //italy navigation
    var italy_navigation = '<ul>'
        +'<li id="menu-1">Italy stuff</li>'
        +'<li id="menu-2">Italy phones</li>'
        +'</ul>';

    //germany
    var germany_navigation = '<ul>'
        +'<li id="menu-1">Germany stuff</li>'
        +'<li id="menu-2">Germany phones</li>'
        +'</ul>';


    this.get_region = function(item){
        my_region = $ (item).attr ('id');
        return my_region;
    };

    this.make_active = function(item){
        item.each(function(){
            item.siblings().removeClass('flag-active');
        });
        item.addClass('flag-active');
    }

    this.update_navigation = function(my_region){
        var old_navigation = $('#navigation').find('ul');
        var new_navigation;
        if(my_region==='europe_flag'){
            new_navigation = global_navigation;
        }else if(my_region==='uk_flag'){
            new_navigation = uk_navigation;
        }else if(my_region==='germany_flag'){
            new_navigation = germany_navigation;
        }else{
            new_navigation = italy_navigation;
        }

        $(old_navigation).hide().html(new_navigation).fadeIn(800);

    };

    this.combine_all = function(item){
        this.get_region (item);
        this.update_navigation(my_region);
        this.make_active(item);
    };


})(jQuery);

// Main
$(function() {
    $('#flags').find('div').myWidget();
});
```

Comment: Your code could be better. maybe you wanna look at this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/jquery-plugin-template/

Comment: Thanks guys, but I just need to know whether there is something wrong with my code as I'm a newbie in OO programming especially in jQuery area. How my code could correctly be transformed into OO or perhaps using prototypes :( Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Whether I'm using the functions correctly especially this.combine_all = function(item) where I call the other functions. Is this a good practice?

Comment: This is in no way an answer, but here is an improved version I am working for you: http://jsfiddle.net/g6mt2y61/3/ but there is still 1 minor bug. (ignore the alert saying "true")

Comment: Here it is a decently updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/g6mt2y61/5/ which has some new utility functions and is (hopefully) well commented. Below, you will have an example of the usage of some utility functions I made.

Comment: That's brilliant! Many thanks :) It look a bit overcomplicated to me. Is this pure OO programming? So I can pick up your knowledge?

Comment: I don't think it is pure oop programming, but I'm not the right person to debate that. And it isn't as complicated as it sounds. If you remove the comments (most of them) you will see that what "fills" it more and makes it look "scary" is just the amount of lines I use. You might find some weird techniques (like using the array to generate the html) but the essential is there. But is there anything you need to ask about the code? I'm free to answer to any question you might have.

Comment: I see. All I wanted to achieve was to be able to write my code even if it's simple in an OO way. Such as these: [Tutorial](http://thecodecentral.com/2011/11/22/object-oriented-way-of-creating-a-jquery-image-slider) or [Tutorial](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/eventralize/) where you can use event handlers, init, prototype, etc.. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but you will have too much work for something this simple. Creating a slideshow would be a better way to practice. A simple slideshow without jQuery would be an harder challenge for you, but you would practice a lot better in my opinion. But keep in mind that I'm a terrible teacher.

Comment: I know, I was really wondering whether that is possible so that I could learn OO in javascript and jQuery. I'm a very good listener and reader :)

Comment: Ok, I think I did it in OOP. Here's my [post](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69016/attempt-for-oop-in-jquery-is-my-code-good) Do I handle the click event properly?

Answer (score 1):

From a once over:

- Using `each` seems overkill, this works:

  ```
  $.fn.myWidget = function () {
      this.click( function (e) {
          if (e) {
              e.preventDefault ();
          }
          combine_all(this);
      });
  };
  ```

  This code assigns the same function to all elements in `this`, the function has `this` as the clicked element, so that is why you provide to `combine_all`
- JavaScript uses lowerCamelCase so `combine_all` -> `combineAll`, also `combineAll` is not enlightening as function names go
- Your code is repetitive to determine the links, for starters you could do something like this:

  ```
  var country_links = {
    uk     : [ 'UK stuff', 'UK phones' ]
    europe : [ 'EU stuff', 'EU phones' ]
    italy  : [ 'Italy stuff', 'Italy phones' ]
    germany: [ 'Germany stuff', 'Germany phones' ]
  };

   this.updateNavigation = function(my_region){
        var oldNavigation = $('#navigation').find('ul'),
            menuItems = country_links[ my_region.split('_')[0] ];
            newNavigation = '<ul>';
         for( var i = 0 ; i < menuItems.length ; i ++ ){
             newNavigation += '<li id="menu-' + (i+1) + '">' + menuItems[i] + '</li>';
         }
         newNavigation += '</ul>'

        $(old_navigation).hide().html(new_navigation).fadeIn(800);
   };
  ```

  This is not the only approach, but you split data from style, `country_links` has all the data. `updateNavigation` knows how to build a list from that. I did not test this code but you should catch my drift.
- To finish on the first point, I would just call all three functions on top instead of `combineAll`

Comment: Many thanks for your solution. Now I need to make it full OO.

Comment: Ok, I think I did it in OOP. Here's my [post](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69016/attempt-for-oop-in-jquery-is-my-code-good) Do I handle the click event properly?

Answer (score 0):

> Now, I'm not sure whether the code I produced is correct

No. You have coded it so that `get_region`, `my_region`, `make_active`, `update_navigation` and `combine_all` are **global variables** (or properties). If you would have used [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), this had thrown exceptions. You would avoid this by not using the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in anything but constructor functions and instance method, and use [`var` statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) everywhere.

> and efficient OO programming.

I don't see any reason to use OO here. There's no need to have instances of anything around.

Additionally, @konijin has very good points, which I won't reiterate here. You might use more structuring functions than he did if you like that, though.

```
// Widget container
(function($) {
    // Widget container plugin
    $.fn.myWidget = function() {
        return this.click(function(e) {
//      ^^^^^^ Always return your jQuery collection from methods, for chaining
            e.preventDefault ();
//          ^ no need to check for existence of e - jQuery ensures that one is passed
            updateNavigation($(this));
        });
    };

    var countryLinks = {
        uk:      ['UK stuff', 'UK phones'],
        europe:  ['EU stuff', 'EU phones'],
        italy:   ['Italy stuff', 'Italy phones'],
        germany: ['Germany stuff', 'Germany phones']
    };

    function getNavigationFromFlag(flag) {
        var items = country_links[ flag.split('_')[0] ];
        var newNavigation = '<ul>';
        for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i ++) {
            newNavigation += '<li id="menu-' + (i+1) + '">' + menuItems[i] + '</li>';
        }
        newNavigation += '</ul>';
        return newNavigation;
    }

    function getRegion(item) {
        return $(item).attr('id');
    }

    function activate(item) {
        item.siblings().removeClass('flag-active');
        item.addClass('flag-active');
    }

    function updateNavigation(item) {
        var navigation = $('#navigation').find('ul');
        var myRegion = getRegion(item);
        var newNavigation = getNavigationFromFlag(myRegion);
        navigation.hide().html(new_navigation).fadeIn(800);
        activate(item);
    }

})(jQuery);

// Main
$(function() {
    $('#flags').find('div').myWidget();
});
```

Comment: Many thanks for the above. It looks much more cleaner than my version. Although, you said no reason for OO. My aim is to learn OO in this particular plugin. How your solution would look like in OO? I very much appreciate your help in advance!! :)

Comment: But there is no application of OO in this situation!

Comment: I see. All I wanted to achieve was to be able to write my code even if it's simple in an OO way. Such as these: [Tutorial](http://thecodecentral.com/2011/11/22/object-oriented-way-of-creating-a-jquery-image-slider) or [Tutorial2](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/eventralize/) where you can use event handlers, init, prototype, etc.. Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe make it so that `countryLinks` are passed to your plugin function. Move the functions in an OOP class, and instantiate that with the element and the arguments.

Comment: See? And this is where I'm lost :( _"Move the functions in an OOP class, and instantiate that with the element and the arguments"_

Comment: Ok, I think I did it in OOP. Here's my [post](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69016/attempt-for-oop-in-jquery-is-my-code-good) Do I handle the click event properly?