# Navigation bar built from fetched JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, object-oriented, event-handling

I have finally been able to create my little navigation plugin in an object-oriented way that reads the `li` from a JSON file.

Now, is my code efficient? Especially, the click function within `getRegion` function?

Is this the correct way to handle the click events in OO?

Here's is working version: [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/hreDws8HwTzDOHDhgkao?p=preview)

```
'use strict';
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {

    Object.create = function (obj) {
        function F () {
        }
        F.prototype = obj;
        return new F ();
    };
}

(function ($, window, document, undefined) {

    var Navigation = {
        init: function (options, elem) {
            var self = this;

            self.elem = elem;
            self.$elem = $ (elem);

            self.url = 'data.json';

            self.navigation = ( typeof options === 'string' )
                ? options
                : options.navigation;

            self.options = $.extend ({}, $.fn.drawNavigation.options, options);

            self.cycle ();
        },

        cycle: function () {
            var self = this;
            self.fetch ().done (function (results) {
                self.buildFrag (results);
                self.display ();
                self.getRegion ();
            });
        },

        buildFrag: function (results) {
            var self = this;
            var navigationRegion = self.options.navigation;
            self.list = $.map (results[navigationRegion].navigation, function (obj, i) {
                return $ (self.options.wrapEachWith).append (obj);
            });
        },

        fetch: function () {
            return $.ajax ({
                url: this.url
            });
        },

        display: function () {
            this.$elem.hide().html (this.list).fadeIn(800);
        },

        activate: function (item) {
            $ (item).siblings ().removeClass ('flag-active');
            $ (item).addClass ('flag-active');
        },

        getRegion: function () {
            var self = this;
            $ ('#flags').find ('div').on ('click', function () {
                //activate flag
                self.activate (this);
                self.options.navigation = $ (this).attr ('id').split ('_')[0];
                self.fetch ().done (function (results) {
                    self.buildFrag (results);
                    self.display ();
                });
            });

        }
    };

    $.fn.drawNavigation = function (options) {
        return this.each (function () {
            var navigationBar = Object.create (Navigation);
            navigationBar.init (options, this);
        });
    };

    //default
    $.fn.drawNavigation.options = {
        navigation: 'uk',
        wrapEachWith: '<li></li>'
    }

}) (jQuery, window, document);

$ (function () {
    $('#navigation').find('ul').drawNavigation({});
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Now, is my code efficient?

We don't care. There's not much going on here, there are not thousands of elements in the DOM, and there are no tight data processing loops. If the UI feels sluggish, something must have been gone horribly wrong.

However, there is one inefficiency in your code that matters: The JSON file is fetched on really every single click. I'm pretty sure this is not desired.

It would be OK if you expect it to change really often (that is, < 15min); or if the response would be dynamically created and you did transmit the currently selected option as a parameter.

> Especially, the click function within getRegion function? Is this the correct way to handle the click events in OO?

Yes, that's fine.

---

However, a few oddities I found in your code:

- You use `Object.create` and an `init` function. That's OK if you *want* to do it that way, and good to understand prototypical inheritance. Yet, I think using a constructor function and `new` is simpler, as it requires only a single call for instantiation.
- Using `self` in your `init` function is unnecessary. Just use `this`, as you do in `fetch` or `display`.
- Why assign `.elem`? You never need it.
- The url should definitely not be a constant, but go into the options. `'data.json'` may be the default value.
- `navigation` is not the most descriptive property name. From the usage, I'd expect an adjective like `current` or `selected` in the name.
- You use `options.navigation` to create `self.navigation` before assigning it a default value.
- `cycle` is not an optimal name either, it sounds as if it cycles through the options periodically. Name it after what the method actually does - or just inline it into the initialisation code.
- I'm not entirely sure what `getRegion` does and whether it needs to go into the `fetch` callback. If you move it outside, you might avoid the code duplication with the `fetch` in the click handler below.
- You shouldn't use `options.navigation` for storing the state, but the `this.navigation` property (which you created in `init` but never use it) - both in `buildFrag` and the click handler.
- Why does `buildFrag` assign to that `list` property? Instead, `return` your result from the method! `display` should then take this as a parameter (or you inline it right away).
- `getRegion` is misnamed as well. The only code that is "getting the region" is `$ (this).attr ('id').split ('_')[0]`. What your whole method does is something like `setupRegionSelectHandlers` or so.
- What is `$ ('#flags').find ('div')`? This shouldn't be static, make the selector an option. Also, it would get clearer if those selection-sensitive divs were stored in a property similar to `.$elem` - I assume they're not descendants of each other?
- As said above, the clicks shouldn't `fetch` the file again. Instead, store the promise for the result on your instance, and reuse that for every display.

I'd do something like this:

```
(function ($, window, document, undefined) {

    function Navigation(options, elem) {
        if (typeof options === 'string')
            options = {navigation: options};
        this.options = $.extend ({}, $.fn.drawNavigation.options, options);

        this.$elem = $(elem);
        this.$selects = $(this.options.select)

        this.navigatedRegion = this.options.navigation;

        this.fetched = $.ajax({
            url: this.options.url
        });

        this.display();
        this.setupSelectionEvents();
    }

    Navigation.prototype.display = function () {
        var self = this;
        return this.fetched.then(function(results) {
            self.$elem.hide().html(self.buildFrag (results)).fadeIn(800);
        });
    };

    Navigation.prototype.buildFrag = function(results) {
        var self = this;
        return $.map(results[this.navigatedRegion].navigation, function(obj, i) {
            return $(self.options.wrapEachWith).append(obj);
        });
    };

    function activate(item) {
        $(item).siblings().removeClass('flag-active');
        $(item).addClass('flag-active');
    }

    function getRegion(item) {
        return $(item).attr('id').split('_')[0];
    }

    Navigation.prototype.setupSelectionEvents = function() {
        var self = this;
        this.$selects.on('click', function () {
            activate(this);
            self.navigatedRegion = getRegion(this);
            self.display();
        });
    };

    $.fn.drawNavigation = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            new Navigation(options, this);
        });
    };

    //default
    $.fn.drawNavigation.options = {
        navigation: 'uk',
        wrapEachWith: '<li></li>',
        select: '#flags div',
        url: 'data.json'
    };

}(jQuery, window, document));
```

Comment: Brilliant. Many thanks for your feedback.You some very good ideas here. However, when I try to run your code solution it does not work. The problem starts in this line 'this.$selects = $(this.options.select)' Can you help me to run your code please?

Comment: Doesn't the selector work? How does your HTML look like?

Comment: ok, I fixed it. The problem was `self.options = $.extend ({}, $.fn.drawNavigation.options, options);` I used `this` instead `self`

Comment: Ah, of course...

Comment: :) One more question. If I was going to create more click, hover, mousenter, etc events, could I wrap them all inside the `setupSelectionEvents`

Comment: Yes, you can. But you might want to rename it to just `setupEvents` then…

Comment: Sorry to bother. Now I have a problem. I'm trying to access each li within the navigation. So that when I click on li I get for instance this.id or change the color of it. Because setupSelectionEvents() is fired after the li are created in DOM I don't have access to those li's :( I would like to create click function for li's inside setupSelectionEvents()

Comment: You mean it's called *before* the DOM `<li>`s are created? But there's a [solution for that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/203198/1048572) as well.